# Error with Kinesis when use a lot of connection

Tags: java, exception, amazon-web-services, jmeter, amazon-kinesis

I'm using Kinesis to store records sent from Jmeter installed on EC2 server.
The problem is that when I launch 7200 threads and use 1 shared on my Kinesis stream, all works fine. If I launch 9000 threads I receive this error

```
Rate exceeded for shard shardId-000000000001 in stream Jmeter under account 769870455028. (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException; Request ID: 98f687d9-ffbe-11e4-a897-357ee8c24764)
```

So I increse the number of shard, setting it to 2 and 3 but it doesn't work.
So I think that the problem isn't the shard number but my java code or i don't know what else.
This is my code:

```
  public MyKinesisClient( String streamName, int partitionKey, String accessKey, String secretKey, String endpoint, String serviceName, String regionId ) {
        this.streamName=streamName;
        this.partitionKey=partitionKey;
        AWSCredentials credentials = null;
        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        kinesisClient = new AmazonKinesisClient(credentials);
        kinesisClient.setEndpoint(endpoint,serviceName,regionId);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo utilizzato per l'invio di un json a Kinesis
     * @param json: com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject da inviare a Kinesis
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public void sendJson(JSONObject json) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, JSONException {
        try{
        PutRecordRequest putRecordRequest = new PutRecordRequest();
        putRecordRequest.setStreamName(streamName);
        putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(json.toString().getBytes("utf-8")));
        //putRecordRequest.setData(ByteBuffer.wrap(String.format("testData-%d", createTime).getBytes()));
        putRecordRequest.setPartitionKey(String.format("partitionKey-%d", partitionKey));
        kinesisClient.putRecord(putRecordRequest);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

There is an instruction to use more shard?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I resolved using two Partition Key. From Amazon definition:

> Partition key is used to segregate and route records to different shards of a stream. A partition key is specified by your data producer while adding data to an Amazon Kinesis stream. For example, assuming you have a stream with two shards (shard 1 and shard 2). You can configure your data producer to use two partition keys (key A and key B) so that all records with key A are added to shard 1 and all records with key B are added to shard 2.

It is obvious that i have to use one partition key for each shard
But this is enough important:

> As a result of this hashing mechanism, all data records with the same
>   partition key map to the same shard within the stream. However, if the
>   number of partition keys exceeds the number of shards, some shards
>   necessarily contain records with different partition keys. From a
>   design standpoint, to ensure that all your shards are well utilized,
>   the number of shards (specified by the setShardCount method of
>   CreateStreamRequest) should be substantially less than the number of
>   unique partition keys, and the amount of data flowing to a single
>   partition key should be substantially less than the capacity of the
>   shard.

Comment: So did you configure yours to use shard 1 until it was full and then switch to shard 2 for new connections? Or just round-robin them since you know you will be under the 2 shard limit? It seems counter intuitive that you need to specify which shard to use.  That would seem to leave extra resources available in shard1 as you expand instead of just accepting more connections as you add more shards.

Comment: I used both shard together, I only split threads into 2 shard.
I don't know if exist one way to use more shards with one partition key.
Surely with my solution there is a waste of resource into each shard

Comment: You can also **randomise** the partition_key in each call to provide even distribution

Comment: Now that makes a lot more sense!.  The one key to one shard seemed to be wasting resources.

Comment: i am triyng with randomization. The documentation is a bit confusing on this point. I don't undestand why if i use one thread group and one shard all works fine, if I use 6 thread group and 6 shards I receive  Rate exceeded exception

Comment: with random partition key works, but the question above remains

Answer (score 0):

@luca
if you use 6 thread group and 6 shards you will receive Rate exceeded exception. Because There is a limitation of 5 getRecord requests per second per shard.
Please refer [Read Throttle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-additional-considerations.html)